# How do you determine the client side NAME of a server control?

Tags: asp.net

Let's say I have a DropDownList server control, called "CategoriesDDL" and the ClientID proeprty determines its client side id, which is its ID prefixed with the id's NamingContainer's ids. In this case the client side ID is CP1_CategoriesDDL. But what is the rule regarding the client side name, in this case "ct100$CP1_CategoriesDDL"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any chance you're simply after the [Control.UniqueId property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid.aspx)?

Server side, this will return the client side "name" attribute value of the control.

Comment: Control.UniqueId is exactly what it is name on client. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Are you using ASP.NET 4? If thats the case, the default for the ClientIDMode property on server controls is "Predictable". If you change that to Auto, you will get same client id and client name except `"_"` and `"$"`. So on the Server Side, you can use client id, replace `"_"` with `"$"` to get the client name.

Also look out for the `ClientIDMode="Static"`, this will simplify it greatly.

If you are not using ASP.NET 4, seems there is some different reason for your issue.

Comment: As he's asking for the name rather than ID, it's better to just request the UniqueID directly, rather than doing a replace on the .ClientID properly.